# Reemplazar valores como `Null`, `TRUE`, `String` y demás dentro de matrices 2 x 3

Tags: javascript

Necesito saber cómo puedo reemplazar valores como `Null`, `TRUE`, `String` y demás dentro de matrices 2 x 3. No puedo utilizar `.map()` y demás. Solo *Js Vanilla*.

Mi ejercicio era el siguiente: cambiar el valor *null* por *Jerry* (aclaro, cambiarlo del array, reemplazar el valor no de forma únicamente visual por consola.)

```
onst mice = [

["lucas", "camila", "pedro"],

["juan", "luisa", null]
];
```

Y estuve intentando, pero lo último que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
function cambiarValor (mice) {

    
for (let i = 0; i < mice.length; i++) {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < mice[i].length; j++) {
    }

    if(i == null){
        i = 'Jerry'
    }
    

return mice
}

}
```

Comment: 1. ¿onst o `const`? 2. `.map()` también es parte del javascript vainilla (javascript puro). ¿Te referías a no usar métodos del lenguaje?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo así

```
const  mice= [["lucas", "camila", "pedro"],["juan", "luisa", null]]

var newMice = mice.map(x => {
    if(Array.isArray(x)){
       const b = x.map(y => {
           if(y === null) return "Jerry" 
           return y;
       })
       return b;
   }
   return x;
})

console.log(newMice)
```

el map recorre y devuelve un array de la misma longitud, luego chequeas que cada elemento del array sea un array y vuelves a hacer un map, y en este mapeo, si un elemento es null, lo modificas por lo que quieras